# Need to configure .htaccess, so multiple folders will act as if they are their own separate root folders - for the code running on them

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For example:

```
mydomain.com/site1
mydomain.com/site2
```

I need to install an application on /site1 that will think that it is on the root folder. (In this case PHP, js, CodeIgniter, but could be anything)

So for example, links/references for files such as **"/file.jpg"** (in code that is in the site1 folder, such as at **mydomain.com/site1/code.js**) will really load from **mydomain.com/site1/file.jpg**
And also the code would not be able to see any folder below site1, so that is basically the root folder. And similar thing would be at site2, so the 2 are separate root folders.

I thought this would be some kind of simple .htaccess file installed at mydomain.com/site1 with a redirect, or some kind of a reverse proxy, but so far everything I tried did not work.
I can't seem to find even any such example even on stack overflow..
Any ideas?

Comment: One idea was to create subdomains, install the apps on their root folders at the subdomains, and then somehow map it to the folders

Comment: Another idea is to find a way to setup separate virtual hosts on apache, then map them to the folders

Comment: You are trying to solve a symptom instead of curing the cause. The cause is your application logic which should not have a problem with being operated under a URL that is _not_ the root path.

Comment: This is a solution that I need to provide to be able to host legacy applications, and some other issues would be greatly reduced if I can solve it this way.

Comment: "In this case PHP... Codeigniter...anything" - Do you mean from PHP (and server-side code) itself? Or only with regards to client-side requests? "or some kind of a reverse proxy" - from what to what?!

Comment: The idea is that this "folder" in the url will act as if it was a subdomain. So all the implications regarding root folder being one level up, in references in any code.

Comment: And "any code" is server-side code as well?

Comment: Yes, php in this case. I see from the answer below that subdomains + reverse proxy sounds like a possible temporary solution, I wonder if anybody has ideas exactly how it can be done?

Comment: Why does it have to appear in the URL as a subdirectory? Why not a subdomain?

Comment: Some clients ask for subdirectory instead of subdomain. They don't understand the issues that I have.. :-)

Comment: Maybe, but in the comments below you stated that this would be "a temporary solution until the root cause is fixed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to create an additional VirtualHost, for internal use, called internal1, whose RootDirectory is, you guessed it, `/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs/site1` where the main site is in `/var/www/mydomain.com/htdocs`.

Then in mydomain.com you reverse proxy `/site1` to internal1 (you'll have to put it into `/etc/hosts` and alias for localhost).  The second request will have its DOCUMENT_ROOT point to `site1`, as requested (and its ServerName changed to internal1):

```
ProxyPass        /site1/   http://internal1/
ProxyPassReverse /site1/   http://internal1/
```

(Not sure about the trailing slashes)

Now, accessing yourdomain.com/site1/joe.html will trigger a second internal connection to internal1/joe.html, which will contain, say, 'src="/joe.jpg"'; and here's where ProxyPassReverse will come into play, rewriting this in 'src="yourdomain.com/site1/joe.jpg"' so that everything will work.

## errata corrige

The above is not correct, thanks @MrWhite for pointing this out. ProxyPassReverse is not enough as it only rewrites *headers*. From the Apache documentation (emphasis mine):

> Only the HTTP response headers specifically mentioned above will be
> rewritten. Apache httpd will not rewrite other response headers, nor
> will it by default rewrite URL references inside HTML pages. This
> means that if the proxied content contains absolute URL references,
> they will bypass the proxy. **To rewrite HTML content to match the
> proxy, you must load and enable mod_proxy_html**.

(The method is dirty as all Hell: every HTTP call incurs one extra connection and two rewrites, one going in, a larger one going out).

Of course, if the link is built using e.g. Javascript, it might well be that the proxy code will not recognize it as a link, will leave it unchanged, maybe with the "internal1" name inside somewhere, *and the app will break*.

However, @arkascha has the right of it - you should cure the cause, not the symptom. You can maybe rewrite the environment of the apps so that they run without troubles even if they are in a subdirectory. Or you could try injecting `<base href="https://example.com/site1">` in the output HTML.

Comment: This is possible, but it includes a performance penalty since each and every request has to get routed though a second, internal http request.

Comment: @arkascha absolutely. But the whole matter is ill-designed, so I feel there aren't *clean and performant* solutions. This should be fixed by whoever coded the legacy apps, *not* by the OP. By the way, when you go the extra mile and deploy this ugly hack, **you** will be blamed for any malfunctions in the legacy code: there's no guarantee that the hack will work in all scenarios. *Been there, done that*.

Comment: @LSerni  Thanks! How do I implement the reverse proxy? This would be a temporary solution until the root cause is fixed. People will be very happy that there is a temporary solution, even if it is slower.

Comment: If you have access to configure vHosts and reverse proxies (but why a rev proxy and not an Alias - isn't this all on the one server?) that you'd have access to configure this properly with a subdomain or something?

Comment: @eyal_katz added the gory details. Let's hope the link scheme of these app is naive enough for ProxyPassReverse to parse, otherwise I'm really afraid you'll be stuck up sh*t creek without a paddle. Perhaps - in a different question - you could give enough details *on the apps* to determine whether it's possible to hack them.

Comment: @LSerni Thanks again! I tried doing this with reverse proxy or aliases before but it didn't work somehow, but I probably don't know enough how to set it up correctly. I'll try your example.

Comment: `which will contain, say, 'src="/joe.jpg"'; and here's where ProxyPassReverse will come into play, rewriting this in 'src="yourdomain.com/site1/joe.jpg"' so that everything will work.` - But that's not what ProxyPassReverse does? To do something like that you'd need to use [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html). Or employ some custom URL-rewrites. Although I would think custom rewrites would be needed, otherwise the root is not "hidden" from client-side JS? Although if `/site1` is present in the URL then client-side JS will know it's not in the root?

Comment: @MrWhite you're right, I remembered incorrectly. Fixing answer

Comment: @eyal_katz I had to fix the answer: I usually enable all proxy modules, but maybe you didn't, and the core proxy module alone *is not enough*.

Comment: Thanks! I'm figuring out what mod_proxy_html does, and what else I have to do - I'll post once I get this to work!

Comment: Ended up cleaning the code the proper way instead of the reverse proxy method.. Thanks for all the info, it may be useful in another situation.